# How can I record the running time of particular commands in Linux (specifically bash)?

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I'm trying to collect some stats on how much time is spent 'waiting' for certain fairly short running tasks so I can justify purchase of some automated tools.  I've written bash function wrappers around a few common tasks I do using the GNU time utility along the lines of this:

```
function something() {
  /usr/bin/time -o ~/wastedtime.log -a $path_to_original "$@"
}
```

I would now like to extend this a little further to a few more scripts & if possible catch the timings for other users on the same machine.  I'm using a [bash to syslog](http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91327) patch already.

**What utilities exist to automatically record the execution times of commands & their arguments?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [GNU Accounting Utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/), specifically the "[sa](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/html_chapter/accounting_6.html#SEC20)" command.